# Okta generating bearer token

Tags: spring, spring-boot, okta, okta-api

I am having
Client ID   0oazapfXXXXXQdywU0h7
Client secret   ko47sxXjXBZlXXXXXXXXXXXVbT9wLyP
issuer, token_endpoint and authorization_endpoint.

How can I generate bearer token Programmatically or via postman.
I am using spring boot.

Comment: Based on which flow you are using, you can go through Okta documentation and use the endpoints mentioned. This is the documentation for one of the flows -https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/implement-oauth-for-okta/request-access-token/

Comment: You should never post your client secret in a public forum or in a publically available source code repository. Now that you have, I'd suggest deleting your app and creating a new one.

Comment: I have masked it with XXXXXXXXXX.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which OAuth2 flow you choose, you can use Okta SDK: https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot

You can find some samples here: https://github.com/okta/samples-java-spring

If you want to take the API route, details are here: https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/